# python-mysqldb without transactions

Tags: python, mysql, transactions, mysql-python

I'm reading about how do transactions work in python's `MySQLdb`. In [this tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/), it says that:

> In Python DB API, we do not call the BEGIN statement to start a
>   transaction. A transaction is started when the cursor is created.

So a following line:

```
cur = con.cursor()
```

starts a transaction implicitly. It also says, that:

> We must end a transaction with either a commit() or a rollback()
>   method.

Do I understand it correctly, that `MySQLdb` uses transactions *always* and there's no way to turn this behavior off? Forcing user to enclose all queries in transactions seems a bit strange. If so - is there any explanation why is that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a huge expert in this, but I think the feature you're looking for here is autocommit.
This automatically commits your commands. Therefore you should be able to skip the 'BEGIN' statements.

Here's a page on it:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html

You set this up when you start the python MySQLdb instance:

```
conn=MySQLdb.connect(host='blah', autocommit=True)
```

You should then have a connection that doesn't worry about Transactions.

Some storage engines don't use transactions so if you use one, you won't need to worry about this detail:
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_MySQL_database_engines

However, they can run into issues if your insert \ update fails halfway through!

Comment: thanks for the tip, but this doesn't really answer the question, which is: does MySQLdb always start transactions and you can't turn it off.

Comment: Depends on your storage engine. If you choose a different storage engine, you'll be fine: